# Change menu text color when div element touches menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, divi

I'm trying to make it so that when the white section of the page at https://staging8.nex.io/ touches the menu items, those `<a>` tags turn the color `#141414`. Then, when you scroll past the section, they turn back to `#fff` as the default color. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You are not likely to get a good response with this question. Create the [simplest, shortest code example that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [IntersectionObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)s, and create as many of them as you have white divs.

if your site needs to support IE11, you'll need to polyfill intersectionObserver

( [source](https://caniuse.com/intersectionobserver) )